# How can i fix a multiplicity issue in mathematica 10.0 loop?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics, polynomial-math

I am solving a project in Mathematica 10 and I think that the best way to do it is using a loop like For or Do. After build it I  obtain the results I looking for but with a to much big multiplicity. Here is the isolated part of the  code:

```
(*Initializing variables*)
epot[0] = 1; p[0] = 1; \[Psi][0] = HermiteH[0, x] E^(-(x^2/2)); 
e[n_] := e[n] = epot[n];

(*Defining function*)
\[Psi][n_] := \[Psi][n] = (Sum[p[k]*x^k,{k,0,4*n}]) [Psi][0];

(*Differential equation*)
S = - D[D[\[Psi][n], x], x] + x^2 \[Psi][n] + x^4 \[Psi][n - 1] - Sum[e[n-k]*\[Psi][k],{k,0,n}];

(*Construction of the loop*)
S1 = Collect[E^(x^2/2) S, x, Simplify];
c = Coefficient[S1, x, 0];
sol = Solve[c == 0, epot[n]]; e[n] = epot[n] /. sol;
For[j = 1, j <= 4 n, j++,
c = Coefficient[S1, x, j];
sol = Solve[c == 0, p[j]];
p[j] = p[j] /. sol;];

(*Results*)
Print[Subscript[e, n], "= ", e[n] // InputForm];
Subscript[e, 1]= {{{3/4}}}
Print[ArrayDepth[e[n]]];
3 (*Multiplicity, it should be 1*)
Print[Subscript[\[Psi], n], "= ", \[Psi][n]]; 
Subscript[\[Psi], 1]= {{E^(-(x^2/2)) (1-(3 x^2)/8-x^4/8)}}
Print[ArrayDepth[\[Psi][n]]];
2 (*Multiplicity, it should be 1*)
```

After this calculation, the question remaining is how do i substitute this results in the original functions. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have a typo in (* Defining function *), [Psi] instead of \\[Psi]. After correction code gives what you say is an expected result.